# SWIFT audioPath = nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mp3, avaudioplayer

I have some code to play an audio file, and it works. When I play any audio file I've previously loaded into the x-code audio asset folder, it works perfectly, here's the code:

```
var audioPlayerOne = AVAudioPlayer()

var randomSound = "worm1"

func playOne(soundOne:String)
{
    do
    {
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundOne, ofType: ".mp3")
        try audioPlayerOne = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        audioPlayerOne.play()
    }
    catch
    {
        print ("ERROR")
    }
}
```

in viewDidLoad I initiate the play:

self.playOne(soundOne: self.randomSound)

last night, all audio files I loaded, caused the app to crash with the following error message:

[image]

I checked, and the files to appear in the directory. What is causing only new files to not be recognized? I also can play the file in x-code, just not through code.

Comment: Maybe the file isn't copied to the final bundle. Take a look at the 'Build phases' to see if everything is alright.

Comment: @McNight That solved it. Any idea why it wasn't automatically added when normally it is?

Comment: Nope sorry, Xcode mystery. There is surely a reason but never took the time to understand why :)